# After some specified character extracting the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can have a Javascript variable as

```
'Ice Creams***Cone***Frosty';
```

OR

```
'Ice Creams***Cone'
```

I need to get the last value after ***

Means in first case i needed the value **Frosty**

and in second case , i needed the value **Cone**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `substr()` and `lastIndexOf()` method

#### Sample

```
function extractEverythingAfter(value, seperator) {
   return value.substr(value.lastIndexOf(seperator) + seperator.length)
}

alert(extractEverythingAfter('Ice Creams***Cone***Frosty', '***'));
alert(extractEverythingAfter('Ice Creams***Cone', '***'));
```

Check out this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/buV58/1/)

#### More Information

- [w3schools - JavaScript String lastIndexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)
- [w3schools - JavaScript String substr() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

Comment: What if the last word contained an asterisk? I.E `value="Ice Creams***Cone***Fro*sty"`

Comment: @dknaack Nice one. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your string on `***` and then use [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last element of the resulting array:

```
var str = 'Ice Creams***Cone***Frosty';
var last = str.split("***").pop();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8vQBR/)

Comment: also maybe `var last = str.match(/\w+$/g)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the last `***` by using [`str.lastIndexOf('***')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).

For getting the last field you can use [`str.substring(index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var seperator = '***'

// shifting index by seperator length
var i = str.lastIndexOf(seperator) + seperator.length;
var lastSubString = str.substring(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above methods will fail if `***` is not found in the input string.

```
var delimiter = '***';
var str = 'Ice Creams***Cone***Frosty';
var strParts = str.split('***'); //returns an array
var numParts = strParts.length;
if(numParts > 0) {
   console.log(strParts[strParts.length - 1]);
} else {
   console.log('Delimiter ' + delimiter + ' not found in input string');
}
```